# Interpret a css keyframe animation at one specific timepoint between two keyframes / Blend two css keyframes

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to make a css animation editor tool using css keyframes animations. 
The idea is to have a timeline to play and preview a css animation, and settle keyframes on.

**The problematic is for the animation preview**, i have to interpolate the style of my html element **at a specific timepoint between two keyframes**. It can be calculated in js for simple value ( such as **top** position number for example ), but in some scenario **it can be tricky to interpolate some css properties in js** ( for example **border-radius**, how to interpolate a value from *"50% 20% 10% 10%"* to *"20% / 10%"* ??? ) 
One idea to solve that is to play and interpret css keyframe animation only at a specific keyframe. 
But it seems to be complicated to play only specific range of a css animation. I know there are the **animation-range**, **animation-range-start** and **animation-range-end** css properties, but these properties are still experimental and does not seems to work in my scenario.

So currently i have no idea how to solve that in the best way. The js interpolation way is doable but complex for specific scenario as explained (how to blend a css border radius style value between **border-radius: 10% 30% 50% 70%;** and **border-radius: 10% / 50%;** ?), and the css way is complex to solve in a proper way.

This is what i tried with css

```html
<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes colorAnim {
            0% {
                color: black;
            }

            50% {
                color: red;
            }

            100% {
                color: green;
            }
        }

        .animated-element-with-offset {
            animation: colorAnim 100ms infinite;
            animation-play-state: paused;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="animated-element-with-offset" id="some-element-you-want-to-animate">
        Text Color Animation frame #50: Color expected is red
    </div>

    <button onclick="interpretAndPauseAnimation(50)">Interpret and Pause Animation at 50%</button>

    <script>
        const element = document.getElementById("some-element-you-want-to-animate");
        let start, previousTimeStamp;

        let duration = 100;
        let endDuration = 49;

        let done = false;

        function step(timeStamp) {
            if (start === undefined) {
                start = timeStamp;
            }
            const elapsed = timeStamp - start;

            if (previousTimeStamp !== timeStamp) {
                if (elapsed > duration * (endDuration / 100)) {
                    done = true;
                    element.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
                } else {
                    element.style.animationPlayState = 'running';
                }
            }

            if (elapsed < duration) {
                // Stop the animation after 2 seconds
                previousTimeStamp = timeStamp;
                if (!done) {
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
                }
            }
        }

        function interpretAndPauseAnimation(keyframePercentage) {
            start = undefined;
            previousTimeStamp = undefined;
            done = false;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }

        window.requestAnimationFrame(step);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rely on negative delays to get a specific point

```css
@keyframes colorAnim {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  50% {
    color: red;
  }
  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}

.animated-element-with-offset {
  animation: colorAnim 100ms infinite paused; 
  /* you can easily set the below using JS */
  animation-delay: -50ms; /* -1 * (50% of the duration) */
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-element-with-offset" id="some-element-you-want-to-animate">
  Text Color Animation frame #50: Color expected is red
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best at controlling CSS animations through JS is certainly the [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API).

You can access a [CSSAnimation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSAnimation) object representing the CSS `animation` you've set on your element and then control its [`currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/currentTime) (and many more if needed). You can access its duration through the [`getTiming()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEffect/getTiming) method of its [`KeyframeEffect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyframeEffect) `.effect`.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("some-element-you-want-to-animate");
// Grab the CSSAnimation object
const [anim] = element.getAnimations().filter((anim) => anim.animationName === "colorAnim");
// Get its duration and possible delay
const { duration, delay } = anim.effect.getTiming();

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.oninput = (evt) => {
  // Since the animation repeats, a value of 1 would reset to black
  anim.currentTime = delay + (duration * input.valueAsNumber);
};
input.oninput();
```

```css
@keyframes colorAnim {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }

  50% {
    color: red;
  }

  100% {
    color: green;
  }
}

.animated-element-with-offset {
  animation: colorAnim 100ms;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-element-with-offset" id="some-element-you-want-to-animate">
  Text Color Animation frame #50: Color expected at start is red
</div>

<input type=range min=0 max=0.99 step=0.01 value=0.5>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  This is a js solution that can be convenient ! This is exactly what i want to achieve, thanks a lot !